# Canceling credit memo gives error

Tags: magento-2.2.5, creditmemo

I am canceling credit memo using below code:

```
foreach ($collection as $creditmemo) {
    if($creditmemo->getState() != 3){
            $order = $creditmemo->getOrder();
            $creditmemo->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo::STATE_CANCELED);
            foreach ($creditmemo->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $item->cancel();
                $item->save();        
            }
            $creditmemo->save();
    }
}
```

The above code gives the following error:

> We found an invalid quantity to refund item

The `cancel()` method checks the quantity available for a given item using `isQtyAvailable()` method which is returning `0`.

I also tried the following solution:

```
foreach ($creditmemo->getAllItems() as $item) {
    // $getQtyReturned = $item->getOrderItem()->getQtyRefunded();
    // $creditmemoQty = $item->getQty();
    // $item->getOrderItem()->setQtyRefunded($getQtyReturned - $creditmemoQty);
    $qty = $item->getQty();
    $item->getOrderItem()->setQtyRefunded($item->getOrderItem()->getQtyRefunded() - $qty);
    $item->getOrderItem()->setTaxRefunded(
        $item->getOrderItem()->getTaxRefunded() -
        $item->getOrderItem()->getBaseTaxAmount() *
        $qty /
        $item->getOrderItem()->getQtyOrdered()
    );
    $item->getOrderItem()->setDiscountTaxCompensationRefunded(
        $item->getOrderItem()->getDiscountTaxCompensationRefunded() -
        $item->getOrderItem()->getDiscountTaxCompensationAmount() *
        $qty /
        $item->getOrderItem()->getQtyOrdered()
    );
    $item->save();        
}
```

The above solution works, but during the creation of a credit memo for the same order again, it gives the subtotal of credit memo as `0`.